# ffmpeg to capture screenshot from a video file in a fine time unit

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to capture screenshot from video. Here is the command code:

```
ffmpeg -i /my_video_file_dir/video.flv -y -f image2 -ss 8 -sameq -t 0.001 
-s 320*240 /image_dir/screenshot.jpg
```

And I want to capture the screenshot at a fine time unit 8.344 for example

But it does not output screenshot image by the above command

In my test, -ss 1,1.5,2,2.5 ... works fine and others not such as 1.1,1.11

Does andbody know why it happens and how can I capture screenshot at a x.xxx time

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01.01 -i /my_video_file_dir/video.flv -y -f image2 \
   -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 /image_dir/screenshot.jpg
```

Note that very small increments will not normally result in different images, due to lower frame rates of most videos.  0.001s increments only work with videos of 1000fps framerates :)  0.03 increments should work with a 30fps video, etc.

Comment: I get the corresponding relation between increments and framerates, thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look to the following shot:

Comment: This is a real solution:

ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 out.png

Comment: could you look at my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189948/ffmpeg-is-not-creating-screenshot-from-video

Comment: I second @user352353's note, but per https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking put the `-ss` flag before the `-i` flag for *much* faster performance! If someone wants to make an account on FFMPEG's Trac and update this wiki page, please do: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video